# Java & OpenStreetMap - Execution time of a query

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am doing an open linked data App and I am downloading information from Open Street Map. My app creates routes around some monuments of Madrid and then uses OSM to get restaurants, pubs, cinemas, etc. around every monument. The actual script that I am using is this one:

```
<osm-script>
<query type="node">
  <around radius="150" lat="40.4188346862793" lon="-3.6948211193084717"/>
  <has-kv k="amenity" v="pub"/>
</query>
<print limit="5"/>

<query type="node">
  <around radius="500" lat="40.4188346862793" lon="-3.6948211193084717"/>
  <has-kv k="amenity" v="cafe"/>
</query>
<print limit="10"/>

<query type="node">
  <around radius="500" lat="40.4188346862793" lon="-3.6948211193084717"/>
  <has-kv k="amenity" v="cinema"/>
</query>
<print limit="5"/>

<query type="node">
  <around radius="500" lat="40.4188346862793" lon="-3.6948211193084717"/>
  <has-kv k="amenity" v="theatre"/>
</query>
<print limit="5"/>

<query type="node">
  <around radius="150" lat="40.4188346862793" lon="-3.6948211193084717"/>
  <has-kv k="amenity" v="bar"/>
</query>
<print limit="5"/>

<query type="node">
  <around radius="250" lat="40.4188346862793" lon="-3.6948211193084717"/>
  <has-kv k="amenity" v="restaurant"/>
</query>
<print limit="6"/>

<query type="node">
  <around radius="500" lat="40.4188346862793" lon="-3.6948211193084717"/>
  <has-kv k="amenity" v="bicycle_parking"/>
</query>
<print limit="5"/>

<query type="node">
  <around radius="500" lat="40.4188346862793" lon="-3.6948211193084717"/>
  <has-kv k="amenity" v="pharmacy"/>
</query>
<print limit="5"/>

<query type="node">
  <around radius="500" lat="40.4188346862793" lon="-3.6948211193084717"/>
  <has-kv k="amenity" v="taxi"/>
</query>
<print limit="5"/>

<query type="node">
  <around radius="100" lat="40.4188346862793" lon="-3.6948211193084717"/>
  <has-kv k="amenity" v="fast_food"/>
</query>
<print limit="7"/>

<query type="node">
  <around radius="500" lat="40.4188346862793" lon="-3.6948211193084717"/>
  <has-kv k="amenity" v="bank"/>
</query>
<print limit="10"/>  

<query type="node">
  <around radius="500" lat="40.4188346862793" lon="-3.6948211193084717"/>
  <has-kv k="amenity" v="parking"/>
</query>
<print limit="12"/>

<query type="node">
  <around radius="200" lat="40.4188346862793" lon="-3.6948211193084717"/>
  <has-kv k="highway" v="bus_stop"/>
</query>
<print limit="8"/>  

</osm-script>
```

I have created a Thread Object in Java which just makes a postForObject with a RestTemplate Object to http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter with the indicated query. I am confused with the timestamps, because I get this:

```
Time Overall for Download 40.427398681640625: 1945 milliseconds
Time Overall for thread Thread-14: 1959 milliseconds

Time Overall for Download 40.40608596801758: 1542 milliseconds
Time Overall for thread Thread-15: 1552 milliseconds

Time Overall for Download 40.41420364379883: 4082 milliseconds
Time Overall for thread Thread-16: 4093 milliseconds

Time Overall for Download 40.412384033203125: 4038 milliseconds
Time Overall for thread Thread-17: 4049 milliseconds

Time Overall for Download 40.41496658325195: 8187 milliseconds
Time Overall for thread Thread-18: 8198 milliseconds
```

More threads, more time for the query. I don't understand that.
There is a way to improve my thread or improve the query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would probably be helpful to mention which Overpass server you're using (I'm guessing it's a public one and not your own)?